# Where can I find HTML template in Jasper reports code to modify it?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want dynamic *html* page when I export the Jasper report to *html* format. To apply *Js* frameworks to make it dynamic i want to grab the *html* generated. But the problem is that the *html* generated is not complete to be applied framework(like Jquery) directly.

I gues there must a *html* template at the back in which data is filled in Jasper reports. Where can I find that *html* template in Jasper reports code?

Can I modify the *html* template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no html template but an exporter configuration for HTML (see [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/export/JRHtmlExporter.html)). In order to enrich the exporter with functionality I suggest to develop a custom exporter by extending the existing `JRHtmlExporter`. In order to do so you'll need to register an extension point and implement the custom HTML exporter.

Comment: But how does **JRHtmlExporter** creates html for html document? Actually I need to insert "thead" tag into it. How can I do so?

Comment: best is to donwload JasperReports sources - the JRHtmlExporter translates JR configurations into HTML (see sources here: http://goo.gl/BbA1F, see for credentials http://goo.gl/8UA8A). In order to extend it you'd start with a JR Extension, register the custom exporter and add the logic you need. It might be helpful to know that you can define custom properties on any element in JR which you can utilize within the exporter.